# escape symbols in python script

Tags: python

I write some automation python script for my rpi project ... here the part of script :

```
import socket
import sys
import platform
import uuid
import psutil
import subprocess
import os
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
from subprocess import call
def measure_temp():
        temp = os.popen("vcgencmd measure_temp").readline()
        return (temp.replace("temp=","").replace("'C\n",""))

while True:
        print
        print 'Hostname:' +socket.gethostname()
        print 'Machine :' +platform.machine()
        print
        print 'CPU Usage:'
        print(psutil.cpu_percent())
        print
        print 'MEM Usage:'
        print(psutil.virtual_memory().percent)
        print
        print 'Disk Usage:' 
        print(psutil.disk_usage('/').percent)
        print
        print 'CPU Temp:'
        if measure_temp() == "50.1":
          GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
          GPIO.setwarnings(False)
          GPIO.setup(22,GPIO.OUT)
          print "Fan on"
          GPIO.output(22,GPIO.HIGH)
          time.sleep(50)
          print "Fan off"
          GPIO.output(22,GPIO.LOW)
          time.sleep(10)
          GPIO.cleanup()
        print(measure_temp())
        time.sleep(10)
        os.system('clear')
print 'end'
```

my problem is in this line :

```
if measure_temp() == "50.1":
```

I want escape all symbols after first number like this :

```
if measure_temp() == "5\":
```

but it does not work. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: What about `if float(measure_temp()) >= 50` You would need to be certain that `measure_temp` always returned a string that could be converted to a float.

Comment: In most languages `"` character is used to identify strings/text. Seems like in python to declare decimals is just `50.1`

Comment: @bradbury9 ``measure_temp`` returns a string

Comment: what do you mean with *escape all symbols after first number*? Can you explain better what you want to achieve?

Comment: It's not quite clear what you mean with "escaping all symbols after the first number". What are you trying to achieve with this? As the other comments mention, it (might) make more sense to convert the `measure_temp` to a number and take it from there. Depends however what you are trying to do.

Comment: @MikeScotty Thanks for the correction, guess some parsing should be done then. Convert the measure temp into a number and check against the numeric value. Also should consider checking if temp measured is greater or igual 50. Is sensor goes from 50 to 52 your fan would not start.

Comment: this script its to display basic system info of my rpi in loop and start vareous components connected to rpi ... now to start cpu fan i need to rich 50 C ... script need format of temperature 50.0 , or 50.1  ... becouse data updated every 10 sec temperature may reach 50.2 or 60 ... and script not will start the fun ... he is will wating for 50.1 .... i want it to start fun ... when themperature over 50 C .... the best for me its  use  <  symbol and not == or ascape all symbols after 5 ....  sorry my english is not so well ...

Comment: @Chris , You are my Hero !!!! its works like sharm !! here what i change  : if float(measure_temp()) >= 50:

Comment: @xanpx Glad this worked for you. I will add it as an answer.

Comment: @Chris , thank you a lot , i need time to understand how this web is work .... to use it correct ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`measure_temp()` seems to return a string. I would convert this to a `float` type first and then check if the value is greater than 50.

```
if float(measure_temp()) >= 50:
    # Your code
```

You would need to be certain that `measure_temp` always returned a string that could be converted to a float.

Answer (score 0):

You may replace your `measure_temp()` with the following, that returns `float`, that is easier to deal with:

```
def measure_temp():
        temp = os.popen("vcgencmd measure_temp").readline()
        try :
                t = re.findall( r'temp=([\d\.]+)', temp )
                t = float(t[0])
        except :    # something went wrong
                print 'unable to convert the temperature:', temp
                t = 20.0   # room temperature
                pass
        return t
```

and `import re` somewhere in the beginning of the file.

Once done, you may compare the temperature value with the numbers, like `if temperature > 50` or something.

And just in case you're wondering, your recent changes 'if float(measure_temp()) >= 50:' will eventually break when `vcgencmd` stalls or returns an empty string or something that cannot be easily converted to `float`, you ought to handle exceptions for your scripts to run smoothly.